# Error - gulp serve not loading the webpart page

Tags: spfx-webparts

I am trying to set up my dev environment for SharePoint online based on Microsoft guide line.
The video is SharePoint client-side web part (Hello World part 1), and I am having an issue when I am trying to run the gulp server. I am not receiving any error messages. It's just the page not loading and giving This site can't be reached a message.
I also notice the URL is different from the one in the video.
The other thing I noticed is missing is the below line:
**Starting subtask 'configure-sp-build-rig'**
**Finished subtask 'configure-sp-build-rig'**

- node.js 14.16.0
- gulp CLI 2.3.0 and Local 4.0.2

[image]

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been several changes made to the SharePoint Framework in the last couple versions. Having to set the URL used by the `gulp serve` task is one of them. Here are links to updated tutorials on building client-side web parts.

First, run the SharePoint Framework Yeoman generator to determine which version of the SharePoint Framework you have installed.

[image: SharePoint Framework Yeoman Generator]

If it's version 1.14.0, then follow this tutorial. Follow the instructions in the article, not in the embedded video. The video was recorded using an older version of the SharePoint Framework (v1.10.0).

[Build your first SharePoint client-side web part (Hello World part 1)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-9698)

If it's version 1.13.0 or 1.13.1, the follow the instructions in this exercise in the in the **Develop web parts with the SharePoint Framework** Microsoft Learn module.

[Exercise - Create a SharePoint Framework client-side web part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/sharepoint-spfx-web-parts/3-exercise-create-web-part?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-9698)

To answer your specific question, you need to update the `initialPage` property of the **serve.json** file to include the URL of a site in your SharePoint tenant.

[image: serve.json]

Comment: Thanks Rob, my SharePoint Framework version is 1.13.1. I was reading the doc and I just didn't understand this part where it says: "Open a browser and navigate to the developer site you created in the first exercise".

Comment: @Harris I understand why that is confusing. "... the first exercise" is actually a typo. It is referring to a step in a previous module in the **Extend Microsoft SharePoint** course on Microsoft Learn. It should read ""Open a browser and navigate to any SharePoint site in your tenant". I'll ensure that typo gets fixed when the training module is next updated.

Comment: The instructions to create the developer site referred to in the current instructions are in the **Create a development site collection** of this exercise.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/sharepoint-spfx-get-started/3-exercise-configure-tenant

Comment: Thanks Rob, the way I made it worked was by using Gulp Serve --Nobrowser , and I added my SP online test environment. I did try many many times to get the local host working and I wasnt successful.